# NSManagedObject and Arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've happened to stumble to following code

```
NSManagedObject* object = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", nil];
```

I wonder why this one is actually compiling and does not throw any exception during runtime.

```
po object
```

returns:

> __NSArrayM 0x17005fc20>( First, Second )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C is dynamically typed.  There is a mismatch there, and the compiler should be generating warnings on that assignment, and on any messages you pass to "object" that NSManagedObject doesn't support.  However, this is completely valid.  Just please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess it's because `NSManagedObject` inherits from and conforms to [`NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html), as does [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).